# Python error : Extra plot while plotting multiple data files using glob

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, glob

I have the following code where I'm plotting two data files "data_1.txt" (quadratic function) and "data_2.txt" (cubic function) using the glob with wildcard `*`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

#fig,ax = plt.subplots()

path = "data_*.txt"
for datafile in glob.glob(path):

    #data = np.loadtxt(datafile)
    data = np.genfromtxt(datafile)
    #print(data)
    #ax.plot(data)
    plt.plot(data)
    #plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])  # This line works

plt.show()
```

However, this is generating an extra plot (red colored line)!

[image]

If I use `plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])` instead of `plt.plot(data)`, the red line doesn't appear any more.

Any explanation? Also is there any difference between `genfromtxt` and `loadtxt` in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red line you see is really a blue line and a red line on top of each other. Those are the first columns of your data files plotted against their index.

In order to produce a  line plot with matplotlib's `plot` function, one should specify the x and y coordinate array. One option is indeed to use

```
data = np.genfromtxt(datafile)
plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1])
```

Another option would be to unpack the data. So for a two column datafile,

```
x,y = np.genfromtxt(datafile, unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Both options are equally available with `np.loadtxt`. In the respective documentations you will find that [`genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) has a lot more options than [`loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). Those extra options may be usefull for excluding header or footer data or replacing missing values. The return type of both commands is the same.

Comment: Oh thanks. Unless I specify, `plot` doesn't understand which array is to be plotted against which array, I think. :)